# is it possible to use a drawing tablet with my phone?

Tags: tablet, drawing

i have a Huion 420 tablet and a Samsung J7 Prime.
i bought an adapter and connected everything properly but nothing shows up on my screen when i use my pen on the tablet
thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about it, I've just looked around on the internet and came out [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/photoshop/comments/412mrx/how_to_use_an_android_tablet_as_a_wacom_drawing/)